# Why is Bellman-Ford Big-O and not Big-Theta VE?

Tags: time-complexity, bellman-ford

I struggle to understand why Bellman-Ford is O(VE) and not Θ(VE). Doesn't it always run the for-loop of |V|-1 and relax all the edges every time?

Answer (score 0):

Bellman-Ford works better (better than Dijksra’s) for distributed systems. Unlike Dijksra’s where we need to find minimum value of all vertices, in Bellman-Ford, edges are considered one by one

Comment: Does this explain why it is Big-O and not Big-Theta..? If so, please elaborate. @dxcorzo